# How to get JavaScript variables from a script tag using Python and Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to return the "id" value from the variable meta using beautifulsoup and python. This possible? Additionally, I don't know how to find the certain 'script' tag that contains the meta variable because it does not have a unique identifier, as well as many other 'script' tags on the site. I'm also using selenium as well, so I can understand any answers with that.

```
<script>
    var meta = "variants":[{"id":12443604615241,"price":14000}, 
    {"id":12443604648009,"price":14000}]
</script>
```

Comment: What are you trying so far with python?

Comment: @FrankDiGiacomoKnarFTHUNDER Update the HTML with the parent node of the `<script>` tag

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using selenium there's no need to parse the html to get the js variable, just use selenum `webdriver.execute_script()` to get it to python:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://whatever.com/')
meta = driver.execute_script('return meta')
```

And thats it, meta now holds the js variable, and it maintains its type

Comment: Thanks, didn't know it was that simple for my case.

Comment: This works better than expected - "maintains its type" is an understatement. The captured variable, in my case a js array, could be directly used as a Python list!

Answer (score 3):

You can use builtin `re` and `json` module for extracting Javascript variables:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import json
from pprint import pprint

data = '''
<html>
<body>

<script>
    var meta = "variants":[{"id":12443604615241,"price":14000},
    {"id":12443604648009,"price":14000}]
</script>

</body>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
json_string = re.search(r'meta\s*=\s*(.*?}])\s*\n', str(soup.find('script')), flags=re.DOTALL)

json_data = json.loads('{' + json_string[1] + '}')

pprint(json_data)
```

This prints:

```
{'variants': [{'id': 12443604615241, 'price': 14000},
              {'id': 12443604648009, 'price': 14000}]}
```

Comment: That seems like the right idea, but i got an error: stating "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable," remember that there are about 50 other script tags without any unique identifier on the site sometimes, so i think I need to find this unique one with the variable meta in it. Don't know if that's the problem, thanks

Comment: @FrankDiGiacomoKnarFTHUNDER I don't know the structure of the html code you have, so helping you is hard without knowing it. All I can say it's selecting the script you want and having the right regular expression to extract the variable.