# Cannot find JavaScript variable from script tag using Selenium with Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I wanted to retrieve a variable named "stats" from the site https://csgostats.gg/player/76561198087162515 using Selenium with Python with the following code:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("https://csgostats.gg/player/76561198087162515")
stats = browser.execute_script("return stats")
print(stats)
```

However, the console returns an error saying "match is not defined". When I use inspect element on the site, I can clearly see the stats variable as shown here:
[stats variable inside script tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPfkL.png)

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong here? The code I'm using seems to work for variables from other websites so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I'm pretty new to this stuff so any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: If you aren't able to find a solution using selenium, you may want to try using BeautifulSoup to parse the HTML of the page to get the `stats` variable. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51780317/7253453  -- you would need to do `soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'lxml')` to parse the HTML of the webpage. Not as elegant, but a workable solution nonetheless

Comment: I see. I tried to use BeautifulSoup at first but I wasn't able to access the website for some reason using requests.get. I kept getting a response 403 from the url I posted above even after setting my User-Agent properly. Also, chrome loads the webpage normally even in icognito mode so I'm confused why I can't get a response 200 for that webpage

Comment: Were you using selenium to `.get()` the page? Or were you using `requests`. If it is the latter, that's likely the reason, as `requests.get()` is not javascript enabled, whereas `selenium.get()` is. You'll want to `.get()` the page with selenium, *then* parse the `.page_source` with BeautifulSoup

Comment: Okay looks like I got it to work correctly. The variable I was looking for actually rests in a piece of commented-out code so I found a way to find all comments. From there I'll just use some way to parse the variable. Thanks a ton!

Comment: No problem, happy to help!