# How to run javascript function in browser with selenium?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, browser, console

I need to send sessionId in `POST request`. (no problem with this). Before these, I need to run the code in the console and get the response back using `Selenium` (in the screenshot). Please help, I couldn't find a solution. I only need a code snippet that runs a script in the console and gets a response (`driver.execute_script` maybe)

[image]

Comment: share some code. what u tried so far? if u got errors, share them too. this way u get more chances to be helped

Comment: Sorry, I didn't try because I have no idea how to do it

Comment: I only need a code snippet that runs a script in the console and gets a response

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get JavaScript variables from a script tag using Python and Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51778105/450121)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)

driver.get("url")
test = driver.execute_script('return _sift_session_id')
print(test)
```

Answer (score 0):

Selenium webdriver can execute Javascript. After loading a page, you can execute any javascript you want. A webdriver must be installed for selenium to work. All it takes to execute Javascript is calling the method execute_script(js) where js is your javascript code.